# Is feeding wild pigeons really "weakening the entire species"?

Tags: ecology, food, literature, animal-husbandry

While reading about what foods are healthy for pigeons, I came across the following paragraph: ([Source](https://animals.mom.me/what-not-to-feed-pigeons-12150945.html))

> Human interaction and improper feeding of domestic and wild pigeons is believed to be one of the reasons for the birds' decline. While many urban areas claim that pigeon populations are out of control, the truth is that around 59 species are currently threatened by extinction, which is over 20 percent of the pigeon population. Since the 1600s, 10 species of pigeon have become extinct. While habitat loss and over-hunting are partly to blame, bird specialists believe that domestication and improper feeding has weakened the entire species.

There are no sources cited. What does "weakening the entire species" even mean? What evidence is there to support the claim that improper feeding is weakening entire species of pigeons? How would overfeeding by humans lead to extinction? And how would domestication be contributing?

Comment: This might be a good question for [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: I did wonder whether an ecology question was on topic for this site. But how would I migrate the question?

Comment: The quote is silly. All the declines noted are for species other than _Columba livia_, the domestic and common wild pigeon. Indeed other species have been lost to habitat loss and hunting, but not to feeding.  Feeding and human activity have helped _C. livia_ explode in population, which is not a sign that (entire) species has been weakened.

Comment: It might also be noted that those extinct pigeon species might well include the dodo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodo

Comment: Yes, [tag:ecology] questions are on topic here.

Comment: Yes, my comment about Skeptics was about the form of the question, not the topic

Comment: Oh, and the passenger pigeon.  Extinction of those had nothing to do with feeding, everything to do with human hunting and the introduction of new predatory species.